# Object's initial data getting reset on updating state using useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement Drag and Drop component offered by react-beautiful-dnd, for mapping courses to a program from a given set of courses available on the database. DND(Drag&Drop) component has 2 columns - Mapped Courses & Available Courses, the data of which is fetched from API. For accomplishing this, I'm make an initialData object, populating it with Mapped Courses & Available Courses fetched from DB, then finally copying this initialData to the columns of DND Component.
Problem - When updating initialData object with 'Mapped Courses', 'Available Courses' is getting reset, and while updating 'Available Courses', 'Mapped Courses' is getting reset.

Code -

```
const MainComponent=()=>{

 //initialData containing courses fetched from DB
 const [initialData, setInitialData] = useState({
    ['Mapped Courses']: {
        name: 'Mapped Courses',
        items: []
    },
    ['Available Courses']: {
        name: 'Available Courses',
        items: []
    }
 });

 //columns of react DnD containing courses after they've been fetched
 const [columns, setColumns] = useState({
     ['Mapped Courses']: {
         name: 'Mapped Courses',
         items: []
     },
     ['Available Courses']: {
         name: 'Available Courses',
         items: []
     }
 });

//react DnD fn for making changes after drag
const onDragEnd = (result, columns, setColumns) => {
    if (!result.destination) return;
    const { source, destination } = result;

    if (source.droppableId !== destination.droppableId) {
        const sourceColumn = columns[source.droppableId];
        const destColumn = columns[destination.droppableId];
        const sourceItems = [...sourceColumn.items];
        const destItems = [...destColumn.items];
        const [removed] = sourceItems.splice(source.index, 1);
        destItems.splice(destination.index, 0, removed);
        setColumns({
            ...columns,
            [source.droppableId]: {
                ...sourceColumn,
                items: sourceItems
            },
            [destination.droppableId]: {
                ...destColumn,
                items: destItems
            }
        });
        console.log(columns);
    } else {
        const column = columns[source.droppableId];
        const copiedItems = [...column.items];
        const [removed] = copiedItems.splice(source.index, 1);
        copiedItems.splice(destination.index, 0, removed);
        setColumns({
            ...columns,
            [source.droppableId]: {
                ...column,
                items: copiedItems
            }
        });
        console.log(columns);
    }
};

useEffect(async()=>{
axios
    .get(`http://programsAPI/program`)
    .then((response) =>
        setInitialData({
            ...initialData,
            ['Mapped Courses']: {
                ...initialData['Mapped Courses'],
                items: response.data.courses.map((course) => ({ id: course.id, content: course.slug }))
            }
        })
    )
    .then(console.log(`Initial Data after Mapping Courses - `), console.log(initialData))
    .then(
        axios
            .get('http://coursesAPI/courses')
            .then((response) =>
                setInitialData({
                    ...initialData,
                    ['Available Courses']: {
                        ...initialData['Available Courses'],
                        items: response.data.map((course) => ({ id: course._id, content: course.info.slug }))
                    }
                })
            )
            .then(console.log('Initial Data after Getting Courses - '), console.log(initialData))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    )
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
)
}, [programLoads])

useEffect(() => {
    setColumns({
        ...columns,
        ['Mapped Courses']: {
            ...columns['Mapped Courses'],
            items: initialData['Mapped Courses'].items
        },
        ['Available Courses']: {
            ...columns['Available Courses'],
            items: initialData['Available Courses'].items
        }
    });
    console.log('Initial Data after setting columns/update');
    console.log(initialData);
}, [initialData]);

return ( 
    //HTML STARTS HERE
)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue is more to do with enqueueing more than a single update to the same state within a render cycle's scope. In other words, in the `useEffect` callback you are enqueueing two state updates that are both updating from the stale enclosure of state.

You can remedy this by using a functional state update so each individual update is applied against the previous state and ***not*** the state value closed over in scope.

You are also declaring the `useEffect` callback as `async` which isn't a correct use of the hook as the callback implicitly returns a Promise which React interprets as a returned effect cleanup function. It's also anti-pattern to declare a function `async` and then use Promise chains instead of awaiting promises to resolve.

Promise chains were also designed/meant to solve a problem of callback nesting, you can return the second `axios` Promise and flatten the Promise chain and use a single `catch`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const courseMapFn = (course) => ({
    id: course._id,
    content: course.info.slug,
  });

  axios
    .get(`http://programsAPI/program`)
    .then((response) =>
      setInitialData(initialData => ({ // <-- previous state
        ...initialData,
        ['Mapped Courses']: {
          ...initialData['Mapped Courses'],
          items: response.data.courses.map(courseMapFn),
        },
      }))
    )
    .then(() => axios.get('http://coursesAPI/courses'))
    .then((response) =>
      setInitialData(initialData => ({ // <-- previous state
        ...initialData,
        ['Available Courses']: {
          ...initialData['Available Courses'],
          items: response.data.map(courseMapFn),
        },
      }))
    )
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  )
}, [programLoads]);
```

This will enqueue two state updates though, an improvement may be to use an `async` function and `await` both GET requests to resolve and map and enqueue a single state update.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const courseMapFn = (course) => ({
    id: course._id,
    content: course.info.slug,
  });

  const fetchInitialData = async () => {
    try {
      const mappedCourseData = await axios.get(`http://programsAPI/program`);
      const availableCourseData = await axios.get('http://coursesAPI/courses');

      setInitialData(initialData => ({ // <-- previous state
        ...initialData,
        ['Mapped Courses']: {
          ...initialData['Mapped Courses'],
          items: mappedCourseData.data.courses.map(courseMapFn),
        },
       ['Available Courses']: {
          ...initialData['Available Courses'],
          items: availableCourseData.data.map(courseMapFn),
        },,
      }));
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    fetchInitialData(); // <-- invoke async funciton
}, [programLoads]);
```